# Call FactoryGirl.create for all rspec controller tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

is there any way you can load some factories for all controller tests? I've got a few of them which are necessary for all controller tests (menu items) and I don't like putting them all in controllers seperately. Not very DRY :)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can take a look at rspec's shared context, highlighted here: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-11/docs/example-groups/shared-context

Answer (score 1):

Create an [RSpec macro](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-13/docs/helper-methods/define-helper-methods-in-a-module!).

Using `user` as the Factory you want to use, here's an example you'd put in `spec/support/controller_macros.rb`:

```
module ControllerMacros
  let!(:user) { FactoryGirl.create :user }
end
```

In your `spec/spec_helper.rb` include the macro for controllers:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.extend ControllerMacros, :type => :controller
end
```

The `let!` is like `let` as if it was referenced in a `before` block.

The `ControllerMacros` is also a handy place to add things like a `sign_in` method, etc.

You can also put [shared examples](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-13/docs/example-groups/shared-examples!) in `spec/support` as well.